# Loading images from a folder in resources ios

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, sprite, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am attempting to load a sprite from a folder using the following statement

```
Sprite *sp = Sprite::create("Images/CloseNormal.png");
```

Now Images is a folder inside resources which has the file CloseNormal.png
The above statement returns `NULL`
Now If I move the image outside the folder into Resources and use the following code

```
Sprite* sp = Sprite::create("CloseNormal.png");
```

The above works

My directory structure in ios looks like this

```
|_Resources
   |_Images
        |_CloseNormal.png
```

Any suggestions why it cant load sprites from folders inside resources ?

Answer (score 1):

it's something about "group or folder" in xcode when add folder into project

also known as "blue or yellow folder"

[image]

when using "create groups", there is no need to use relative path.

oppositely, you must use actual relative path when using "create folder reference"

suggest you searching more about it, like google "xcode group or folder"